# Can a single QueueConnection be used in multithreaded environment.?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, jms, websphere

I have a IBM QM that is configured in IBM WAS. A single **QueueConnection** is created from **QCF and is loaded into memory, so that multiple threads can access the same connection(each thread will create a session out this conn) to send and receive messages from Queue.** I have a performance issue with this approach.

1. While first thread is using the connection, will other threads wait
   until the first send and receive.?
2. If this is the case can I create a connection for each thread.? Will this affect performance.?

I have an application where no.of concurrent requests will be 50 per sec. So I have to deal with the performance issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMS connections (i.e. QueueConnections and TopicConnections) are thread safe and can be used by multiple threads.
All JMS constructs "below" a connection (i.e. Sessions, QueueSessions, TopicSessions) are not, and one should be allocated per thread.

Comment: As all threads use the same connection, does **session.send(msg)** of one thread affect the other threads.? i.e. will other threads wait until a thread finishes its send/receive operation.?

Comment: Thanks. I will try to do a load test and figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Each thread should be sharing a [QueueConnectionFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueConnectionFactory.html) rather than a QueueConnection.

Threads will then create their own QueueConnection from the factory.

Comment: I have 200ms to send and receive the message. Does getting a new connection from QCF affect the performance of the thread?

Comment: What do you mean by send and receive? What are you expecting to get back?

Comment: I have an external system which process the message on request queues and sends response message on response queue. (I'm not using MDB)